# Checking that multiple user inputs meet a certain condition before saving them as variables

Tags: ruby, variables, conditional-statements, user-input, rescue

Is there a way to combine these 2 blocks of code to make it less redundant?

```
puts "first number?"
num1 = gets.chomp.to_i
until num1.is_a?(Integer)
  puts "please enter an actual number"
  num1 = Integer(gets.chomp) rescue nil
end

puts "second number?"
num2 = gets.chomp.to_i
until num2.is_a?(Integer)
  puts "please enter an actual number"
  num2 = Integer(gets.chomp) rescue nil
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that as follows.

```
def get_int(msg)
  puts msg
  loop do
    n = Integer(gets, exception: false)
    break n if n
    puts "please enter an actual number"
  end
end
```

```
num1 = get_int("first number?")
  #=> 16
num2 = get_int("second number?")
  #=> -4
```

The dialog in getting the value for `num1` was as follows.

```
first number?
cat
please enter an actual number
72.1
please enter an actual number
16
```

The dialog in getting the value for `num2` was as follows.

```
second number?
&dog
please enter an actual number
10/2
please enter an actual number
-4
```

See [Kernel#Integer](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) and [Kernel#loop](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop). `Kernel#Integer` was given the optional argument `exception: false` in Ruby v2.6.

One advantage of using `loop` is that it provides a degree of data encapsulation. Unlike `while` and `until`, `loop` takes a block, thereby keeping prying eyes away from the values of local variables defined within the block. I rarely use anything other than `loop` for looping.